# '(maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)' in gmock test

Tags: c++, pointers, googletest, googlemock

I have a unit test using gtest and gmock.

These are provided, and in my turn I should make them pass.

I have a RentalAdministration Object, which takes (in some methods) a Car object pointer. One of the functions looks like this:

```
bool RentalAdministration::Add(Car *car){
    if(!car){
         throw invalid_argument("Car parameter can't be null!");
    }

    if(FindCar(car->GetLicencePlate()) != NULL){
         return false;
    }

    cars.push_back(car);
    return true;
}
```

One of such tests looks like his:

```
TEST(RentalAdministrationAdd, test_add_car_to_empty_administration)
{
    RentalAdministration admin;
    Car *car;
    EXPECT_CALL(car, GetLicencePlate()).WillOnce(Return("fh-01-ict"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(admin.Add(&car));
}
```

When I try to make these tests, I get loads of errors, all of which are alike:

```
g++ -Wall -Werror -pedantic -ggdb -O0 -std=c++98 -Iproduct -Itest test/RentalAdministrationTest.cpp product/RentalAdministration.cpp -lgtest -lgmock -lgmock_main -lpthread -o RentalAdministrationTest
In file included from /usr/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/gmock/gmock.h:61,
                 from test/RentalAdministrationTest.cpp:2:
test/RentalAdministrationTest.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void RentalAdministrationAdd_test_add_car_to_empty_administration_Test::TestBody()’:
test/RentalAdministrationTest.cpp:13:5: error: request for member ‘gmock_GetLicencePlate’ in ‘car’, which is of pointer type ‘Car*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
     EXPECT_CALL(car, GetLicencePlate()).WillOnce(Return("fh-01-ict"));
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/gtest/gtest.h:58:0,
                 from /usr/include/gmock/internal/gmock-internal-utils.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/gmock/gmock.h:58,
                 from test/RentalAdministrationTest.cpp:2:
test/RentalAdministrationTest.cpp:14:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘RentalAdministration::Add(Car**)’
     EXPECT_TRUE(admin.Add(&car));
```

^

I wonder what I am doing wrong here. I'm just starting off with C++.

btw: I am compiling in g++ and have version 98.

Thanks.

Edit: excuse me for not posting this, but I have a mock file for Car.h which is in the same folder as the test itself.

```
#ifndef __CAR_H
#define __CAR_H

#include "gmock/gmock.h"

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Car
{
    public:
        MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetLicencePlate, string());
        MOCK_METHOD0(Rent, bool());
        MOCK_METHOD1(Return, double(int kilometers));
        MOCK_METHOD0(Clean, void());
};


#endif
```

Edit1: As suggested I have tried to use the reference (&) of Car*.
This kills the error I've stated above, but leaves me with some other errors:

```
 error: cannot declare field ‘AdminTest::car’ to be of abstract type ‘Car’
     Car car;

 error: ‘class Car’ has no member named ‘gmock_GetLicencePlate’
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how do you know `cars` is a pointer? Error message doesn't even contain the word `cars`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

For anyone wondering: Inside one class (RentalAdministration) I had included the `Car.h` file from the `cars` folder. (like `#include "cars/Car.h"`)

However, for the test a different `Car.h` should be used. Therefore, changing to `#include "Car.h"` made it work.

Answer (score 3):

`car` is a pointer to `Car`. Its type is: `Car*`. In order to call `Car` members from a `Car*`, you must dereference the pointer. This is automatically done when using the `car->x` syntax, which is equivalent to `(*car).x`.

I assume that `EXPECT_CALL` requires a non-pointer argument. Therefore, you can get a reference to `car` and pass it to the macro:

```
Car& car_ref = *car;
EXPECT_CALL(car_ref, GetLicencePlate()).WillOnce(Return("fh-01-ict"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you are suggesting I rewrite the tests?

Comment: @bart-kn just fix your `test_add_car_to_empty_administration` test with the code I've written above - let me know if it solves the problem

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, but it left me with some other errors. I've updated the question to include some of these errors. Could it be because Car class is abstract? (It has two virtual pure functions)

Answer (score 1):

First is the pointer issue, that Vittorio already said but, also, you need to mock Car object to use EXCEPT_CALL:

```
class MockCar : public Car{
     // Here I assume that original method is const
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetLicencePlate);
}

TEST(RentalAdministrationAdd, test_add_car_to_empty_administration)
{
    RentalAdministration admin;
    MockCar car;
    EXPECT_CALL(car, GetLicencePlate()).WillOnce(Return("fh-01-ict"));
    EXPECT_TRUE(admin.Add(&car));
}
```

You can see in my examle that you are not using real car object but a Mock one where you can control access and force return values

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However I forgot to note that I already have a mock file. (It's provided as well). Please see the updated question.